# Views not appearing for non admin user

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, admin

I have setup a view which outputs nodes, including the name of the person who created it.

If a non-admin person browses to the page where that view is displayed, they dont see the name field, I recall somewhere about this being an administrative permission ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the name of the creator a CCK field?  Make sure the permission to view this field is set for anonymous users (in the /admin/user/permissions page).